# Header expire doesn't work

Tags: php, caching, header, http-headers

I tested this script that I found on [this web site](http://www.sitepoint.com/caching-php-performance/):

```
function setExpires($expires) {
header(
'Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+$expires).'GMT');
}
setExpires(10);
echo ( 'This page will self destruct in 10 seconds<br />' );
echo ( 'The GMT is now '.gmdate('H:i:s').'<br />' );
echo ( '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'">View Again</a><br />' );
```

When I refresh the page, the time updates every sec instead of every 10 sec.

**"If we follow this link, we’ll notice the time updates only once every ten seconds"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I'm hoping you didn't make this typo, but I'll point it out to you anyway:

```
header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+$expires).'GMT');
```

Should have a space behind the `seconds` field:

```
header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s ', time()+$expires).'GMT');
//                                       ^-- add space here
```

Comment: still it dosent work... but what i notice that my time is 17:18 pm and the The GMT is now shows 14:18

Comment: You're sure this header is sent though?

Comment: yes the header is sent I also add Cache-Control:max-age=3600 but still it dosent cache it

Comment: Actually, when you hit refresh, the browser is very likely to make another request ... the expires header is there for when you just follow links.

Comment: oo yes if i click on the **View Again** link it really works :D lol i didnt know that thanks @Jack

Comment: But how to make it cache the page even when the refresh is cliked ?

Comment: @EvenJohnson Unfortunately - and to my knowledge - this is not possible as it's expected behaviour of a browser to refresh the page when Refresh is clicked :) that said, elements of the page (e.g. images, scripts) work differently.

Comment: and if use htaccess to cache only this file ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11334/discussion-between-jack-and-even-johnson)